# Is there a name of this problem?

Tags: algorithms

There is $n$ lists (of integers) of the same length. 
I want to find the zeros global intersections of those lists.

Example:

$A = [4,6,3,0,7,0,0,0,1,0,0]$

$B = [6,6,7,1,7,0,0,0,4,0,0]$

$C = [2,4,7,0,7,0,0,0,3,0,0]$

The output are the position of those intersections: 
[image]

The positions are $5, 6, 7, 9$ and $10$

Other than "traversing" the list and checking element by element, is there another way ?

Comment: What does "zeros global intersections" mean?  Can you [edit] your question to state the task more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no asymptotically better deterministic algorithm than the one that just checks, for each position $i=1,\dots,n$ whether $A[i]=B[i]=C[i]=0$.

This is easy to see since any correct algorithm must read at least one entry per value of $i$. To see this, suppose that there is an instance
$I = \langle A,B,C \rangle$ for which a correct algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ accesses neither of $A[i]$, $B[i]$, and $C[i]$, for some $i$.

Consider two instances  $I' = \langle A',B',C' \rangle$  and  $I'' = \langle A'',B'',C'' \rangle$ that are identical to $I$ except (possibly) for the fact that $A'[i]=B'[i]=C'[i]=0$ and $A'[i]=B'[i]=C'[i]\neq 0$. Clearly $\mathcal{A}$  must return the same set $S$ of indices on all of $I$, $I'$, and $I''$. If $i \in S$, then $\mathcal{A}$ fails on $I''$, otherwise $\mathcal{A}$ fails on $I'$.

Comment: Why not return not (a[i] or b[i] or c[i])? No if conditionals, and true denotes a 0 in all three arrays at that position.